# How do I get the Korriban title?

Tags: achievements, star-wars-the-old-republic

According to my Codex, I'm missing an "Achievement: Title" for Korriban.

I thought I had done everything on the planet.

What is this title and how do I earn it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't experienced this myself but I did do some forum searching. This post is a few days old but it might be relevant to your problem.

> I'd just like to weigh in and confirm that I completed the "Hate Machine" storyline, and did not receive the "Imperial Scholar" title. I submitted a bug report. Unfortunately, it looks like the Codex: Korriban achievement for Titles is unattainable until this is fixed.

[Source - SWTOR Forums](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=26931)